# Communication between Android service and activity using listener

Tags: android, service, android-activity, communication

Most the examples I see for communication between activity and service are using a BroadcastReceiver.  My question is can I replace the broadcast receiver with just a normal listener?  Then I don't have to worry about marshaling my web service response into a Intent/Bundle class.  Is there anything wrong with this approach?  Anything less advantageous than using a BroadcastReceiver?  AddListener would be called on the Activity's onCreate method and RemoveListener would be called in the Activity's onDestroy method.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AsyncService extends IntentService
{
    static List<WebServiceListener> listeners = new ArrayList<WebServiceListener>();

    public static void addListener(WebServiceListener listener)
    {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public static void removeListener(WebServiceListener listener)
    {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public AsyncService(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000); //simulate calling webservice
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }

        WebServiceResponse response = new WebServiceResponse();
        response.status = "SUCCESS";

        for (WebServiceListener listener : listeners)
        {
            listener.onReceiveResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it is a local service, yes, you can do that